# How to use z-index in tailwindcss for hiding an element behind the parent element?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

The goal is to hide an element behind a parent. There is a relative parent position, and a fixed child position, so when you scroll down, the fixed child will become visible and the parent will go up.

**The image with yellow border shall go behind**

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
<!-- hamburger menu -->
<div class="relative bg-white z-50 border-2 border-purple-900 w-[34%] h-auto flex justify-end items-center">
    <div class="fixed top-6 right-1 z-20 border-2 border-yellow-500">
        <a class="lg:hidden inline-block float-right text-red-600 mr-[3px] mt-1 p-[6px] bg-white rounded-full border-2 border-yagya-red" href="#">
            <button id="mobile_menu1" class="relative outline-none w-7 h-7">
                <div role="hidden" id="line" class="inset-0 w-4 h-0.5 m-auto rounded-full bg-yagya-red transition duration-300"></div>
                <div role="hidden" id="line2" class="inset-0 w-4 h-0.5 mt-1 m-auto rounded-full bg-yagya-red transition duration-300"></div>
                <div role="hidden" id="line2" class="inset-0 w-4 h-0.5 mt-1 m-auto rounded-full bg-yagya-red transition duration-300"></div>
            </button>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To add a z-index you have to use class:

- `z-10` : To bring that element forward
- `-z-10` : To bring that element backward

You can take the below example

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<!-- red with positive z-index -->
<div class="p-10">
  <div class="w-24 h-24 bg-red-600 rounded-full z-10 absolute"></div>
  <div class="w-24 h-24 bg-blue-600 rounded-full mt-10"></div>
</div>

<!-- red with negative  z-index -->
<div class="p-10">
  <div class="w-24 h-24 bg-red-600 rounded-full -z-10 absolute"></div>
  <div class="w-24 h-24 bg-blue-600 rounded-full  mt-10"></div>
</div>
```

FInd more [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/z-index)